# Old singer sewing machine m4

Tags: capacitor

After capacitor been told not to get Rifa has are prone to blowing again need help finding replacement my wife’s only had machine 40yrs any help would be appreciated
[image: rifa pme271m 4/085/56 0022ufxenter image description here]

Comment: If the capacitor takes 40 years to blow, maybe just put another one in there and stop worrying!

Comment: I had to do this. The "new" RIFA was also 40 years old and had degraded in storage (aging plastic film, I think). It lasted a couple of days, not 40 years. I ended up using modern equivalent film caps, X (X2?) rated.

Answer (score 2):

If you get RIFA again you're worried about what might happen after 2063?

Anyway, you can substitute an X safety-rated ceramic capacitor such as [W1X223MCVCF0KR](https://www.vishay.com/docs/22201/w1x.pdf).